# 20.04: Update on my dual-boot situation

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have a Dell Inspiron One 2020 AIO with Windows 10 1909 installed, to which Ubuntu 20.04 was added for dual boot.

I have figured out why GRUB isn't loading after I boot into Windows.

I inserted the Ubuntu USB drive I burned into the PC which allowed to boot into the live Ubuntu. Then I restarted the PC, removed the USB and striked F2. I changed the boot device to ubuntu, which allowed the computer to see Windows and Ubuntu. Anytime I want to boot into Windows, ubuntu is no longer detected as a boot device and its replaced with Windows Boot Manager. Any way I can boot into Windows and still have Ubuntu as the default boot device?

Answer (score 1):

I had a strange requirement (when I reboot, the UEFI boot menu does not display on my external monitor and I don't want to have to hope up my docked laptop each time I reboot).  So I have UEFI only boot to Grub and then use Grub to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.  An added benefit, I can select the next boot option from within Windows and Ubuntu.

In my BIOS, I set Ubuntu as the only boot option (removing Windows from the menu).

In Ubuntu, I moved Grub from /boot to /boot/efi/EFI (which is a FAT32 partition created by Windows).

Here are the steps I went through to install Grub into the EFI partition (/dev/nvme0n1 is the disk Windows is installed which contains the EFI parition, nvme0n1p2; Ubuntu is on nvme2n1):

1. grub-install --boot-directory=/boot/efi/EFI --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/nvme0n1
2. cp -R /boot/grub/* /boot/efi/EFI/grub/
3. mv /boot/grub /boot/grub.old
4. ln -s /boot/efi/EFI/grub /boot/grub
5. grub-set-default 2 # The auto-detected Windows boot option
6. cp /boot/grub/grubenv /boot/grub/grubenv.windows
7. grub-set-default 0 # The first boot option -- Ubuntu
8. cp /boot/grub/grubenv /boot/grub/grubenv.linux

Now, if I want to boot to Windows, I run:

- sudo cp /boot/grub/grubenv.windows /boot/grub/grubenv
- sudo reboot

If I want to boot to Linux, I run:

- mountvol x: /S
- copy /Y x:\EFI\grub\grub.linux x:\EFI\grub\grubenv
- mountvol x: /D
- shutdown /r

Bonus benefit: I can be remote (via RDP or SSH) and reboot into my other OS.